# how to get the method return as a string ?while inner methods or a query are in Object type?

Tags: java, string, jakarta-ee, jdbc, methods

Please help me with this method.
There are two methods returning as Object, I'm confused to store
 output of return statement of if in outer  String method

```
public String getLogin(StudentTO sto) {
    String u = sto.getUsername();
    String p = sto.getPassword();

    String sql = "select * from studentstable";

    Object obj = JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, new RowMapper() {
        public Object mapRow(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
            rs.beforeFirst();
            while (rs.next()) {
                String userdb=rs.getString("username");
                String passdb=rs.getString("password");
                String roledb=rs.getString("role");
                if(userdb.equals(u) && passdb.equals(p) && roledb.equalsIgnoreCase("admin")) {
                    return "ADMIN";
                } else if(userdb.equals(u) && passdb.equals(p) && roledb.equalsIgnoreCase("user")) {
                    return "USER";
                }
                Object obj=string;
            }
            return obj;
        }
    ///errror i dont know how to call object here or a string
    // commented out line because it is misplaced.
    //return rs;
    });

    StudentTO sto1=(StudentTO)obj;
    System.out.println(sto1);
    return sto1.toString();
}
```

I want the method `getLogin()` to return `ADMIN` or `USER`.

Comment: You can `throw` a new exception in case of error. Do you know how to work with Exceptions in Java?

Comment: Please read all those explanations on how to format your postings. Your question is really formatted  in weird ways.

Comment: plz can any body give m the solution to get result to my prblm

Comment: @MiguelKVidal ya i know exceptions

Comment: @GhostCat sorry for the bad formatt buddy now can you help me out of this

Comment: You should be doing the lookups with a WHERE clause, not scanning the entire table.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's change your `getLogin()` method a little bit:

```
public String getLogin ( StudentTO sto ) {
    String uName = sto.getUsername();
    String uPass = sto.getPassword();

    String uRole = findUserRole( uName, uPass );

    if( "admin".equals( uRole ) || "user".equals( uRole ) ) {
        return uRole .toUpperCase();
    }

    throw new RuntimeException( "Wrong role!" );
}
```

It's a simpler version of your method.

Then, you just need to implement `findUserRole()`:

```
public String findUserRole( String name, String pass ){
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM studentstable where username = ?";
    // execute and fetch data
    if( passdb.equals( pass ) {
        return roledb;
    }
    throw new RuntimeException( "User not found or wrong password." );
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: what about JdbcTemplate And queryForObject

Comment: it is must to use rowMapper to select the db

Comment: Do you *MUST* use `JdbcTemplate` and `RowMapper`?